# Rails 3 - where clause on has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

**Hi there,**

I have a little problem with a where query on a has_many :through association...

My setup is as follows:

**PurchaseOrderAddressAssignment:**

```
belongs_to :address

belongs_to :purchase_order
```

**Address:**

```
has_many :purchase_order_address_assignments

has_many :purchase_orders, :through => :purchase_order_address_assignments
```

**PurchaseOrder:**

```
has_many :purchase_order_address_assignments

has_many :addresses, :through => :purchase_order_address_assignments
```

**My where clause:**

```
PurchaseOrder.where("addresses.id = 168 and addresses.id = 169").includes(:addresses)
```

Is returning 0 Records... but there should be at least 1...

```
PurchaseOrder.where(:baan_id => "KD0005756").first.address_ids
```

Is returning [168, 169, 170, 327]

... I think I'm too stupid to solve this little problem :-/

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thx,

Michael

Comment: Try changing this `PurchaseOrder.where("addresses.id = 168 and addresses.id = 169").includes(:addresses)` to `PurchaseOrder.where(addresses.id => [168,169]).includes(:addresses)` and see what happens.

Comment: thx for your response. I forgot to say that I already tried the where clause with IN(...). The problem here is that if I'm using where("addresses.id IN(n1, n2, n3)") the query will return about 1000 PurchaseOrders... In my scenario there is only 1 PurchaseOrder with address_ids = [168, 169, 327]

Comment: `addresses.id => [168,169]` should limit to just those two.

Comment: `PurchaseOrder.where("addresses.id" => [168,169,327]).includes(:addresses).count` is returning 972. `PurchaseOrder.where("addresses.id = 327").includes(:addresses).count` is returning 1. I allways thought that the first query should return the same thing as in my second query... I'm a bit confused :-/ I need to get the value as in my second query.

Comment: My apologies I got thrown off... you need the one where it is 168 AND 169 AND 327?

Comment: Yes - I need only the purchase orders which contains the addresses 168 AND 169 AND 327. `PurchaseOrder.where("addresses.id = 168 AND addresses.id = 169 AND addresses.id = 327").includes(:addresses).count` is returning 0. In my opinion this should work.. But it doesn't :-/

Comment: Now I follow you... my apologies. `addresses.id` looks like Rails syntax and I noticed you used `address_ids` when discussing the table earlier. What happens with `where("address_id = 168 AND address_id = 169 AND address_id = 327")`?

Comment: it's returning an empty array. Following query is fired up. `"SELECT `purchase_orders`.* FROM `purchase_orders` WHERE (addresses.id = 168 AND addresses.id = 169 AND addresses.id = 327)"`

Comment: What happens when you play around with it, e.g. `where("address_id = 168 AND address_id = 169)` or `where("address_id = 168 AND address_id = 327")`?

Comment: in both cases empty arrays. Well... I could add 3 new columns to PurchaseOrder (address_1, address_2, address_3) and then do `PurchaseOrder.where(:address_1 => 168, :address_2 => 169, :address_3 => 237)` this would return 1 record "as expected" but it's kinda ugly :P

Comment: Agreed that is ugly and unecessary. I am sorry this is not working out.

Comment: found something that works... `PurchaseOrder.includes(:addresses).group("purchase_orders.id").having("count(addresses.id)=3").where("addresses.id = 168 or addresses.id = 327 or addresses.id = 169")` is returning only 1 record... yay.. won't be able to use that in my ap. `count(addresses.id)=3` only works if I'm using 3 ids ><. There must be some other way to solve this problem

Comment: I am sure there is something I am missing. I am going to start a Bounty on this and see if I can get another set of eyes

Comment: Michael, when one of the answers works for you give it a check and I will award the bounty

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would probably do a custom finder method in this case.

```
class PurchaseOrder < ActiveRecordBase
  def self.with_addresses(*args)
    values = args.flatten.uniq

    # Note use :joins instead of :includes if you don't
    # want the addresses data
    includes(:addresses)
    where(:addresses => {:id => values})
    group("purchase_orders.id")
    having("count(ad‌​dresses.id)=#{values.size}")
  end
end
```

I'm pretty sure that should work.

Here's a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8748964/527152) that helps explain the query.

Answer (score 3):

So you want the `PurchaseOrder`'s where `addresses` are in some id's list

Try this:

```
PurchaseOrder.where(addresses: {id: [168, 169]}).includes(:addresses)
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it will ALL the `PurchaseOrder`s that have 168 or 169, instead of just the `PurchaseOrder` that contains just those addresses.