# Ordering and Filtering on many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to incorporate tags into a website and have been at a roadblock for a few hours now. On my index page, I wanted to display all the articles that have at least all the tags currently selected. I saw [Rails 3 many to many query condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726564/rails-3-many-to-many-query-condition) and added

```
@articles = Article.find_by_sql([ "SELECT * FROM articles p
JOIN (
    SELECT pt.post_id FROM articles_tags pt
    JOIN posts p ON p.id = pt.articles_id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
    WHERE t.label IN (?)
    GROUP BY pt.post_id
    HAVING count(pt.post_id) = ?
) pt ON p.id = pt.post_id", names_array, names_array.size])
```

but now I want to include the user who created it and order it by its timestamp.
It wont let you include or order by the results of find_by_sql

help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the authors are in table 'creators', how about this:

```
@articles = Article.find_by_sql([ "SELECT * FROM articles p
JOIN (
    SELECT pt.post_id FROM articles_tags pt
    JOIN posts p ON p.id = pt.articles_id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
    JOIN creators c ON c.id = p.creator_id
    WHERE t.label IN (?)
    GROUP BY pt.post_id
    HAVING count(pt.post_id) = ?
) pt ON p.id = pt.post_id ORDER BY articles.created_at", names_array, names_array.size])
```

Comment: This didnt work. It returns an empty array. If I remove the join you added, the ordering works. I tried to look at the sql for what a normal includes().order looks like but it is identical to a .orders

Comment: I ended up having to use two queries to do this.